# Accessing OSX Scrollbar preferences programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to programmatically access the state of some of the settings in my SystemPreferences. In particular the scrollbar settings (for 10.7 whether they're floating or not and for 10.6/10.5 the scroll button placement). I know there's these .plist files, but I'd much rather access something fast from memory if possible. I'm curious as well if there's away to be notified when they change, so that I don't have to read them so often.

Comment: Could you please describe how do you intend to use this, I really don't quite understand your question, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm working in another language environment, but want to adapt the UI elements I create to be different based on which mode the system is doing its scrollbars currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [NSScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScroller_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference. The change in the setting is automatically communicated to all instances of `NSScroller` by calling the appropriate `setArrowsPosition:` etc. You just need to implement them in your `NSScroller` subclass.

Comment: Problem is that I'm not coding in Objective-C in this case. I'm trying to emulate certain aspects here. Or at least respond appropriately. I can make Objective-C calls if need be to global things to do queries.

Comment: THen, create a dummy `NSScrollView` and `NSScroller` in a hidden window. I believe that receives the notification. By the way, which framework do you use? Any modern framework (supporting 64 bit) eventually calls Cocoa in the end, because that's the only GUI API officially exposed by Apple.

Comment: I work on VisualWorks Smalltalk, a cross platform Smalltalk environment. It emulates (kind of) a lot of its graphical stuff.

Comment: Quick googling shows that you can call Cocoa from VisualWorks, http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/userblogs/mls/blogView?entry=3421240130  If you really need to emulate OS X appearance, you need to be very careful; the scroller changes shape even with the type of mouse you connect to the Mac!